# Vue: v-model undefined or default/fallback

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Is there anyway to set a default value to an input to the value of another input field in case it has been left empty.
Looks like I can't specify this in the data nor in the v-model attribute:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="number" v-model="font1 || 14"> <!-- gives error -->
        <input type="number" v-model="font2 || font1"> <!-- gives error -->
        <input type="number" v-model="font3 || font1"> <!-- gives error -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            font1: 14,
            font2: this.font2 || this.font1, // this approach also gives error
            font3: this.font3 || this.font1 // this approach also gives error
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to define a default value of the variable (font1) or the input field?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, just want to make sure that the first input isn't left empty and the other 2 would be optional with a fallback to the input of (font1), so actually none can be empty, so font1 would have a default value set, and font1 and font2 would have font1 value as a default, and model this font1 in case it changes and they are not set themselves. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably 37 different ways of doing it.

The question is what is important, robustness, maintainability, ease of implementation, scalability etc.

Here is a solution that prioritizes ease of implementation. It relies on using `@change` and `:value` instead of the `v-model` magic.

This will leave `font2` and `font3` as null if they are not changed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    font1: 14,
    font2: null,
    font3: null,
  },
  methods: {
    isNumber(n) { return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && !isNaN(n - 0) }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="font1">
  <input type="number" @change="font2 = $event.target.value" :value="isNumber(font2)?font2:font1">
  <input type="number" @change="font3 = $event.target.value" :value="isNumber(font3)?font3:font1">
<pre>{{ {font1:font1, font2:font2, font3:font3} }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: But in this case, fields can be left empty, if field is left empty it should be defaulted back to input 1's value. This is probably because it returns empty string which is not equal to null.

Comment: updated answer to include erasing value using `isNumber` method

Comment: Yup, this is definitely one of the 37 ways to achieve this, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a combination of `v-model` and computed properties' getters and setters to achieve what you want.

1. Declare an internal data store for the fonts, let's call the `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`. Give `f1` your default value of 14:

   ```
   data: function()  {
     return {
       f1: 14,
       f2: null,
       f3: null,
     };
   }
   ```
2. Now, when the component is mounted, you will want to interpolate the values accordingly. This can be done in the `vm.mounted()` callback:

   ```
   mounted: function() {
     // f2 takes the value of f1, if itself is falsy
     this.f2 = this.f2 || this.f1;

     // f3 takes the value of f2, if itself is falsy
     this.f3 = this.f3 || this.f2;
   }
   ```
3. The last step is to setup your computed properties, so that whenever `font1`, `font2`, or `font3` changes, they will update the internal font data store appropriately:

   ```
   computed: {
     font1: {
       set: function(val) {
         if (val)
           this.f1 = val;
       },
       get: function() {
         return this.f1;
       }
     },
     font2: {
       set: function(val) {
         this.f2 = val || this.f1;
       },
       get: function() {
         return this.f2;
       }
     },
     font3: {
       set: function(val) {
         this.f3 = val || this.f2;
       },
       get: function() {
         return this.f3;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#test',
  data: function() {
    return {
      f1: 14,
      f2: null,
      f3: null,
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.f2 = this.f2 || this.f1;
    this.f3 = this.f3 || this.f2;
  },
  computed: {
    font1: {
      set: function(val) {
        if (val)
          this.f1 = val;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.f1;
      }
    },
    font2: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.f2 = val || this.f1;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.f2;
      }
    },
    font3: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.f3 = val || this.f2;
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.f3;
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test />
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="test">
    <div>
        <input type="number" v-model.number="font1">
        <input type="number" v-model.number="font2">
        <input type="number" v-model.number="font3">
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, only problem with this is that by default input 2 and 3 are 'empty' and inherit value of input 1, if input 1 is changed --> input 2 and 3 inherit updated value as well, unless they were modified independently. It is kind of confusing I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Boolean set to false for both `input 1` and `input 2` elements and update it to true when a value is entered.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    font1: 14,
    font2: {
      value: 14,
      defined: false
    },
    font3: {
      value: 14,
      defined: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Chg(font) {
      if (font.value.length) {
        font.defined = true;
        return;
      }
      font.value = this.font1;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    font1() {
      if (this.font2.defined === false) this.font2.value = this.font1
      if (this.font3.defined === false) this.font3.value = this.font1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="font1">
  <input type="number" v-model="font2.value" @input="Chg(font2)">
  <input type="number" v-model="font3.value" @input="Chg(font3)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case it will always inherit changes made to the first input, but I would like the second and third one to be standalone, but if nothing is added to them to inherit input1's value.

Comment: Should they inherit from input1 at a particular event? (In case they're empty).

Comment: Hi @Quentin, they should inherit in case they are left empty (unchanged), if input 1 changes, both the others should update mirroring this value, unless they are set independently before or after. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Almost, seems like this time fields can be left empty though, which is what I want to avoid. But is like 90% correct, so I should be able to figure out this last 10% :)

Comment: Seems like fields are still able to be left empty, no?

Comment: Indeed, it's fixed.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :)